# in the output results need to replace the column names with the names in another table

Tags: sql-server

in ms sql server,
table 1 fields would be a1,a1,a3,a4
and results would be 123456 as a1,hello there as a2, 12.00 as a3, 800 as a4

we have conversion table that states a1=code,a2=description,a3=price,a4=qty.

what i need to do is for the output to include the name of the second table instead of the name of the first table.
this is for a json extract

select a1 as code, a2 as description, a3 as price, a4 as qty
from table1
joint table2 "for the field description value"

need help on this
thanks

Comment: Tables don't have "fields", they have columns and rows.

Comment: As for what you're asking, it sounds like you have a design flaw here, as it *seems* you're suggesting that your design  mandates you use dynamic SQL. If so, you need to fix the design. Sample data and expected results (**not** images) will help us help you, or confirm my suspicions (concerns).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just alias the columns to the names you need them to be?

Comment: @jw11432, the actual database is about 3000 fields (columns) and fields names F01, F02 etc etc etc sread through 130 tables and are not easy to understand and we are migrating to a new app with a new database. Yes I could do the mapping manually but i was wandering if this mapping could be done dynamically when running the query.

Comment: @Larnu, there are no design flaws, it is just the way it was design by the programmer when it was created. once you get to know the naming of the fields then it is easy to create queries.

Comment: @Larnu
here is the query that gives me a concatenate list of the fields table for a specific table.
select F1453+' as '+replace(replace(replace(dbo.fn_initcap(F1454),' ',''),'/','_'),'.','')+',' as fieldsList
from RB_FIELDS
where F1452='vendor_tab'
order by F1453

and it gives the following result

F1000 as targetIdentifier,
F1001 as recordStatus,
F1168 as operatorResponsible,
F1642 as shipIdNumber,
F1654 as freightRateWeight,
F1655 as freightRateVolume,
F1656 as vendorTermDescriptor,
F1685 as backOrderDays,
....
basically what i want in the query to get vendor_tab results

Comment: *"there are no design flaws"* but you stated earlier *"actual database is about 3000 fields"*. I ***assume*** by this you mean the **table** (not database) has about 3,000 columns (not fields) as databases have neither "fields" nor columns. If you have a table with 3,000~ columns then you almost certainly have a denormalisation issue.

Comment: english is not my first language. 3000 columns spread through 130 tables. I know the database as no columns but tables and inside there are columns. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: That's fine, but that doesn't change anything here. You have a design flaw that you need to address and fix. The fact that you **require** dynamic SQL to achieve what you want is more than enough of an indicator to confirm that, but add that to the fact your table has 3,000 columns and there's overwhelming evidence that the database needs to be normalised.

Comment: Larnu, 130 tables for a total of 3000 columns. not one table with 3000 columns.
so there is no design flaw, Just a humongous task it is to manually alias the column to th new column names.

Comment: So any idea on how to do this?